# When I try to make a button show a different view controller using a segue it adds a black bar at the top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

I am using the latest version on Xcode and am trying to connect a button to a new view controller using a segue. In my project I have other buttons that work and the view controller looks normal but when I attach it to this one by control clicking and dragging to another view controller it does this... [image: Image with black space where time and wifi should be]

(There is a black space at the top rather than the usual full page)

I have also tried

```
presentedController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

However this did not work for some reason.
I think a reason that it may not work is because the view controller is disconnected. I need to do this to connect 2 programmatically, how can I fix this?

Comment: That is a modal presentation.  Embed that VC or the root VC in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thanks That was it, I forgot to connect my VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard in segue options choose:
Kind: Present Modally
Presentation: Fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behaviour of iOS 13 modal presentation. If you try with earlier versions than iOS 13 you will see the `fullScreen` presentation. But if you want to use `fullScreen` presentation in iOS 13 either you should set `modalPresentationStyle` of your presented view controller.

```swift
presentedController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```